# How to create a reusable sub-form with react-hook-forms using a subset of the fields of the main form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form, tsx

I am trying to create a reusable form component that uses only the values a subset of the values from the larger value interface. Example:

```js
// I want to factor this out to a separate component
interface JobData {
  position: string;
  salary: number;
}

// This will be the type of the `useForm`
interface Data extends JobData {
  name: string;
  birthDate: string;
}
```

The reusable component, where the control will be typed to the `JobData` interface

```tsx
interface JobFormProps {
  control: Control<JobData>;
}

const JobForm = ({ control }: JobFormProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ControlledInput control={control} controlName="position" />
      <ControlledInput control={control} controlName="salary" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Since it uses only the `position` and `salary` fields, other forms that have these field could reuse this component.

And finally the main form, where I include the `JobForm` component:

```tsx
const MainForm = () => {
  const { control } = useForm<Data>({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "John",
      birthDate: "1980-01-01",
      position: "Developer",
      salary: 100000
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ControlledInput control={control} controlName="name" />
      <ControlledInput control={control} controlName="birthDate" />
      <JobForm control={control} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

With this approach I get a type error when I want to pass the `control` to the `<JobForm>` component.

```
Type 'Control<Data, any>' is not assignable to type 'Control<JobData>'.
  Types of property '_reset' are incompatible.
    Type 'UseFormReset<Data>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormReset<JobData>'.
```

Here is a testable code on codesandbox.io: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-typescript-forked-3jqhkg?file=/src/index.tsx)

How to make such sub-forms in a type-safe way?

Make the `JobFormProps` interface generic

```js
interface JobFormProps<T extends JobData> {
  control: Control<T>
}
```

But this way the field names are not recognized.

Also I tried casting the `control` to the specific type, which lead to the same type error.

```
<JobForm control={control as Control<JobData>} />
```

Setting all the fields in `Data` to optional seems to resolve this type issue, but some fields should be mandatory.

```js
const { control } = useForm<Partial<Data>>(/*...*/);
```

### Edit:

One other viable solution, is to make the `<JobForm>` component generic, and then the control name must be casted to `Path<T>`

```tsx
interface JobFormProps<T extends JobData> {
  control: Control<T>;
}

const JobForm = <T extends JobData>({ control }: JobFormProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ControlledInput control={control} controlName={"position" as Path<T>} />
      <ControlledInput control={control} controlName={"salary" as Path<T>} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround for it:

```
import { Control, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type MyFormData = {
  fieldA: string;
  fieldB: string;
};

const MyForm = () => {
  const { control } = useForm<MyFormData>();

  return (
    <>
      <MyCustomInput
        control={
          control as Control<Partial<MyFormData> & Pick<MyFormData, "fieldA">>
        }
      />
      {/* Other fields ... */}
    </>
  );
};

type MyCustomInputProps = {
  control: Control<{ fieldA: string }>;
  // Or:   Control<Pick<MyFormData, "fieldA">>;
};

const MyCustomInput = ({ control }: MyCustomInputProps) => {
  // Here we can now use <Controller>, useFieldArray(), etc.
  return <></>;
};
```

The key here is in passing `Partial<MyFormData> & ...`, which satisfies the type checking error we both ran into.

All of this allows `MyCustomInput` to exist without knowledge of `MyFormData`, making it reusable in other forms.

Props go to Michał Bundyra who posted a variation of this trick [here](https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/5983#discussioncomment-1080951).